# How to make an animation play when a button is pressed once?

Tags: unity, c#, animation, animator

I have added an idle and jump animation to a character in unity. I can make the animation happen when the button is pressed. If the button is up middle at the animation the character goes to the idle position. But I want the whole animation happen in one press to the button and then go back to the idle position. My current script and Animator views are:

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        Anim.SetBool("is_jumping", true);
        ApplyInput(moveAxis, turnAxis);
    }
    else if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        Anim.SetBool("is_jumping", false);
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a Trigger instead of a Boolean for this.

A trigger is like a boolean, except that it automatically resets itself to false after one frame if you set it to true.

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        Anim.SetTrigger("is_jumping");
        ApplyInput(moveAxis, turnAxis);
    }
```

Note that you will need to replace "is_jumping" with a trigger in the animator.

Comment: it does not go back to idle position. How can i get it back to idle position after the jump animation ends?

Comment: The transition to the idle animation from the jump animation should have "Exit time" checked. This will make the jump animation automatically transition to the idle animation after it ends.